# lstrcpy() causing exceptions in visual C++ code

Tags: exception, visual-c++, mfc, listctrl

I used a MFC virtual list control to enhance the performance and I handle **GetDispInfo(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)** to populate the ListCtrl. The relevant code in that method is as follows:

if (pItem->mask && LVIF_TEXT)
{

```
    switch(pItem->iSubItem)

    {
        case 0:
            lstrcpy(pItem->pszText, rLabel.m_strText);  
        break;
        case 1:
            sprintf(pItem->pszText, "%d", p.o_Value);
        break;
        default:
            ASSERT(0);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here, when I use lstrcpy(),when I'm srolling  down/up, I get a whole lot of exceptions saying **First-chance exception at 0x7c80c741 in test_list_control.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xb70bf2ac.** These messages appear in the debug output. But the program doesn't crash. Can anyone please explain what the matter here and how should I overcome that??

rLabel is a CLabelItem which I have declared earlier.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you see is the first chance exception thing, stop worrying. See for example [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidklinems/what-is-a-first-chance-exception) but you can find similar pages all over the place (mostly from 5-10 years ago.) It means some code threw and the exception was caught and dealt with. I see this in MFC apps some times. As the blog entry says

> First chance exception messages most
> often do not mean there is a problem
> in the code.

I would wait until you see actual errors before getting worked up about this one.

Comment: Thanks Kate, your answer & link helped me get over my doubts... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check if buffer that is pointed by pItem->pszText is large enough to hold rLabel.m_strText. Or if rLabel.m_strText is correct null terminated string. For me this looks like writing uninitialized memory. Use the debugger to check this.